# Linear mixed model ggplot fixed and random effect

Tags: r, ggplot2, mixed-models

In our study, we aim to investigate the evolution of blood pressure (variable `DIASTO`) over time. Time is measured based on the treatment modification date (variable `DELAI_SWITCH`). The objective is to observe if there is a change in the evolution before and after the treatment modification. I needed to employ a two-slope model for this purpose. To achieve this, I utilized the following functions:

```r
Delai = 0
DelaiNeg <- function(x, Delai) ifelse(x < Delai, x, 0)
DelaiPos <- function(x, Delai) ifelse(x < Delai, 0, x)
```

To create the following model, where `PATIENT` represents the identity of each patient:

```r
model_Diasto <- lmer(DIASTO ~ DelaiNeg(DELAI_SWITCH, Delai) + DelaiPos(DELAI_SWITCH, Delai) + (1 | PATIENT), data = IeDEA_BP_Switch)
```

Everything is functioning well for now.
And it gives us this :
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FyA3.png)

which is nicely represented by :

```r
ggplot(IeDEA_BP_Switch, aes(x = DELAI_SWITCH, y = DIASTO)) +
       geom_point(color="royalblue",alpha=0.1) + 
       geom_line(aes(y = predicted_Diasto), color = "red", linetype = "dashed",size=1.1)`
```

[image]

It gets complicated when i try to add some adjustment variable to the model with interaction with `DELAI_SWITCH`.
Everything works fine when i try this model with an adjustment and interaction on `SEX` or with `AGE`

```r
model_Diasto <- lmer(DIASTO ~ DelaiNeg(DELAI_SWITCH, Delai) + DelaiPos(DELAI_SWITCH, Delai) + SEX +(DelaiNeg(DELAI_SWITCH, Delai):SEX)+(DelaiPos(DELAI_SWITCH, Delai):SEX)+(1 | PATIENT), data = IeDEA_BP_Switch,REML=0)
```

The ggplot of predicted estimates also works fine

When I try to model some adjustment and interaction on `AGE` **and** on `SEX`, the model works fine, with these estimates :

```r
model_Diasto <- lmer(DIASTO ~ DelaiNeg(DELAI_SWITCH, Delai) + DelaiPos(DELAI_SWITCH, Delai) +AGE_Switch +(DelaiNeg(DELAI_SWITCH, Delai):AGE_Switch)+(DelaiPos(DELAI_SWITCH, Delai):AGE_Switch)+
SEX +(DelaiNeg(DELAI_SWITCH, Delai):SEX)+(DelaiPos(DELAI_SWITCH, Delai):SEX)+(1 | PATIENT), data = IeDEA_BP_Switch,REML=0)
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/OG5VN.png)

But the ggplot geom_line goes crazy :

[image]

I tried with `geom_smooth`, but realised that the graph didn't properly fit the estimates of the model (for example intercept was wrong..).

If you guys have an idea of how to plot these kind of linear mixed model I would really appreciate it.

I tried several times and looked for answers on Stack Overflow. Some use geom_smooth, which does not seem to fit the estimates in my case. And I've seen no post with the `geom_line` going crazy as it does for me.

Comment: Please share sample data - just 10 or 20 rows should be fine. `dput()` is the nicest way to share sample data, `dput(IeDEA_BP_Switch[1:10, ])` will make copy/pasteable R code to recreate the first 10 rows of `IeDEA_BP_Switch`. Also please share the `ggplot` code for the graph that is not working.

Comment: Without looking too carefully, I think it's possible that some appropriate specification of the `group` aesthetic might help?

Comment: As for `geom_line` "going crazy" - it draws a line connecting all of your data points. If you have a lot of data, that's a lot of lines.